# Having Trouble with return strings from Directory.Getfiles() Method

Tags: vb.net

I'm having some difficulty using the Directory.GetFiles() method.  It's returning information with what looks like extra carriage returns.  The result is that I can't use the strings it's generating to open up any files it finds.

I've tried looking into the overloads for the call without much luck.

```
For Each Filefound As String In Directory.GetFiles(FolderBox.Text, "*.xl*")
                Debug.WriteLine(Filefound + "First")
                ListBox1.Items.Add(Filefound)
```

I was expecting an output like - `D:\Folder\Timesheet.xlsx.`
Instead I'm getting -

```
D:\Folder

\Timesheet.xlsx.
```

I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Have you examined `FolderBox.Text` to see if it has unexpected characters in it? You can use the [`Trim()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=netframework-4.7.2) method with no parameters to remove whitespace characters.

Comment: Is the unexpected output appearing in the debug output, the listbox, or both?

Comment: @Andrew Morton I'm going to assume the `ListBox1.Items.Add(Filefound)` is giving that output/look.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ From the lack of the string "First" it appears so, but let's make sure ;)

Comment: @AndrewMorton it's appearing in both.  The formatting on the dropdown looks correct. but when I run the listbox items through the debug output it's identical.  I just tried calling trim without any luck.

Comment: `ListBox1.Items.Add(Filefound.Replace(vbCrLf, String.Empty))`, try that what does it give you?

Comment: If you change the Debug.WriteLine line to `Debug.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(fileFound).Select(Function(x) x.ToString("X2"))))` it will show the bytes of the characters in hex in the output pane. Anything less than 20 would be suspicious.

Comment: Figured it out.   I made use of the Strings.Replace() Method, and added that newline character to the removal portion.  Had trouble finding it's representation, so I copied it off of the debug output to make it work. 
`For Each Filefound As String In Directory.GetFiles(FolderBox.Text, "*.xl*")
                Debug.WriteLine(Strings.Replace(Filefound, "
", ""))
                ListBox1.Items.Add(Strings.Replace(Filefound, "
", ""))`

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Thanks.  That was the character reference I was looking for.  Makes the code look a lot cleaner.
`Debug.WriteLine(Strings.Replace(Filefound, vbCrLf, ""))`

Comment: @RusticWolf you are welcome, glad you got it working.